Rated current vs melting integral of fuses
I am looking for a fuse for my project, and have become confused about how the current rating and melting integral (I2t) relates to each other.
My understanding is that:

The current rating indicates the current that the fuse may carry continuously, or at least for a long time - See the example from Littlefuse below, indicating that at 100% rating, the fuses will have a minimum opening time of 4 hours.
The melting integral represents the energy required to melt the fuse.
See the same example from Littlefuse below, where the 1 A fuse is listed with melting integral of only 0.02 A2s.

My question is how the value of the melting integral can "lower" than the current rating?
That is, for a square current pulse with a value of Ip, the resulting I2t would be I2t = (Ip)2t, so a limit of 0.02 A2s would be reached after 1 s at a steady current of only 0.02 A (Way lower than the current rating of 1 A).
I have looked at several fuses with this apparent "contradiction", so clearly I have misunderstood something. Will someone please elaborate?



Which datasheet are you referencing?

The I^2t rating is a pulse rating and it applies for short pulses, for example < 0.008 seconds for one particular type, and < 1ms for very fast-break fuses. See the manufacturer's data for more information on what applies.
It's related to the energy required to melt the fuse element assuming essentially adiabatic conditions.
It only increases the current capability of the fuse, it does not decrease it.
It's useful in sizing a fuse that can experience single surges (for example, a turn-on surge) that is far in excess of the continuous rating, a train of high current pulses, or in determining whether the fuse will protect a power semiconductor or not (usually it won't, but it will protect the wiring).
Generally you evaluate the I^2t and (suitably derated) continuous current requirement and use the higher of the two.
Here is a document from Schurter with some examples. Other manufacturers will have similar documents, which are supplemental to the brief datasheets.

Thank you for the answer! I looked through then note you references, but I am still not sure I understand - In the example I included in the question, I would assume that if I apply a square pulse of 0.02 A for 1 s, then I would have reached the energy limit of the melting integral (0.02 A^2s), right? So how does that fit a (continuous) current rating of 1 A ?

Since the pulse time is much longer than 8ms, use the time-current curves rather than I^2t. The adiabatic condition assumption is invalid.

@mjuels: Please note I^2t is a meausre of the energy needed to melt fuse. It can be straightaway related to time, only if energy is not dissipated to outside world ( adipabatic condition). This assumption holds good as long time scale is short and the heat wouldnt have ecsaped out of the fuse unit.

https://forum.digikey.com/t/fuse-i2t-rating-melting-point-and-interrupt-rating/1271

One is not lower than the other, because both are different units.
The melting integral is energy, while the current rating is current.
In your example with 0.02A^2s for 1s you only get 0.141A, but for 0.01s you will get 1.41A which is more than the current rating of 1A.
